# Chime SDK setDeviceLabelTrigger not requesting permissions after first returning a promise

Tags: aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm using Chime Javascript SDK. I firts make users join as view only, so they don't need to approve audio and video permissions in the browser. So, following the documentation, I'm just executing this:

```
this.audioVideo.setDeviceLabelTrigger(() => Promise.resolve(new MediaStream()));
```

Then, when someone enables the option for camera and microphone, I'm executing this:

```
this.audioVideo.setDeviceLabelTrigger(async () => {
   try {
      await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
});
```

But for some reason, the browser it's now showing the modal permissions.

- I checked and i hadn't blocked permissions in the browser.
- I tried in incognito and in a fresh installation of other browsers (firefox, opera)
- If I don't make the first execution, when returning a resolve promise, then it is asking the permissions to ther user.

Any help about what can be happening?

Comment: Hi, have you got it working or found any workaround?